# How does the nature of cricket pitches vary?

Tags: cricket

In cricket playing countries like Australia, South Africa and England, pitches often are thought to support fast and swing bowling. But in the Asian subcontinent and other countries, pitches are typically not too bouncy.

How do cricket pitches vary? Will the weather conditions play a role in affecting cricket pitches?